# Inconsistent state in nested react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a container component that can expand to fit some content, and it should also expand when nested containers are expanded.

the component:

```
export default function ExpandableContainer({expanded , children}) {

const ref = useRef(0)

const [style, setStyle] = useState({"maxHeight": 0})

useEffect(() => {
    setStyle(expanded ? {'maxHeight':ref.current.children[0].getBoundingClientRect().height} : {'maxHeight':0})
},[expanded,children])

return (
    <div ref={ref} style={style} className='xxx'>
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

what im trying to make:

```
export default function Grandparent({expanded}) {

const [childExpanded, setChildExpanded] = useState(false)

return (

<ExpandableContainer expanded={expanded}>

  <div>

    <button onClick={() => setChildExpanded(!childExpanded)}>
      //some stuff
    </button>

  </div>

  <ExpandableContainer expanded={childExpanded}>

      //some stuff

  </ExpandableContainer>


</ExpandableContainer>
)
}
```

this works perfectly fine with the parent component, it expands and closes to the correct size. but on the child component, with the parent open, clicking to open the child does not affect the size of the parent, but the childs size is correct. clicking the button again to close the child makes the parent take the size that it should be when the child is open.

initial

```
parent, props - expanded:false , state {maxHeight:0}
child, props - expanded:false , state {maxHeight:0}
```

parent open button clicked:

```
parent, props - expanded:true, state {maxHeight:77}
child, props - expanded:false , state {maxHeight:0}
```

child open button clicked:

```
parent, props - expanded:true, state {maxHeight:77}  <- should be 355
child, props - expanded:true, state {maxHeight:278}
```

child close button clicked:

```
parent, props - expanded:true, state {maxHeight:355} <- should be 77
child, props - expanded:false , state {maxHeight:0}
```

being new to react I have a feeling that this has to do with some stale state somewhere or with using ref incorrectly but I cant see where. any help would be appreciated

Edit: after some more looking, a potential change was changing setChildExpanded(!childExpanded) to setChildExpanded((prev) => !prev), this had no effect on the problem however

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue here is you are using `useEffect`. There are a few quite limited & specific edge cases where you need [`useLayoutEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect) instead, and this is one of them.

Specifically, if your component needs to read values that first needs a DOM element to be updated to know those values in the first place. The case where your component behaviour depends on measuring the size of something is the most common reason this pops up.

Because the majority of use cases of `useEffect` don't need to do this, and waiting for these values to be available incurs a performance cost, it doesn't wait for this to happen. But `useLayoutEffect` is the escape hatch for when you just need it.

This is why it lags by n+1 states. When the measurements are made, it's done before the changes to the DOM element that are needed to reflect the new state have been effected, and so they are the measurements from the DOM that represent the *previous* state.

This typically incurs some conceptual confusion since it is easy to conflate "re-render" with "DOM updated". Usually, the ambiguity doesn't matter anyway, but here it does.

Whilst changing it to `useLayoutEffect` will probably fix it, I'm slightly curious about the use case since the behaviour you mention in its most basic form can be achieved without having any `max-height` at all and letting the container flow by itself. Though I assume there is a reason (animations perhaps).

Comment: Ive changed it to useLayoutEffect and its giving the same behavior :/. And yeah im using transitions so I cant use maxheight: auto or fit-content